# net.ipv4.conf.all.mc_forwarding: why is my access denied?

Tags: linux-kernel, encryption, key-authentication, multicast

On Debian 12.04 LTS

I am trying to access the key `net.ipv4.conf.all.mc_forwarding` by doing :

> sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.mc_forwarding=1

But every time I am doing this, I get the message

> error: permission denied on key 'net.ipv4.conf.all.mc_forwarding'

Why do I get this message? How can I change this key?

Comment: Because */proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/mc_forwarding* is read-only, even for *root*. [It seems like](http://www.network-builders.com/sysctl-permission-denied-mc_forwarding-keys-t109119.html) you have to run a multicast router instead of turning this option on directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this thread (EDIT: link to bit-coin miner site removed) describes your problem

In a nutshell, the proc entry containing that value is read-only, and cannot be made writable easily:

```
$ ls -ln /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/mc_forwarding 
-r--r--r-- 1 0 0 0 Jun 17 08:20 /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/mc_forwarding
$ sudo chmod u+x /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/mc_forwarding
chmod: changing permissions of `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/mc_forwarding': Operation not permitted
```

But you can run your own router daemon to (e.g [xorp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XORP)) to get multicast forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

you can also get error like this `sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.conf.all.mc_forwarding": No such file or directory`

```
mc_forwarding - BOOLEAN
    Do multicast routing. The kernel needs to be compiled with CONFIG_MROUTE
    and a multicast routing daemon is required.
    conf/all/mc_forwarding must also be set to TRUE to enable multicast
    routing for the interface
```

kernel should be compiled with option CONFIG_MROUTE, default kernel is not have this option set.